# Remove object from NSMutableArray after parsing JSON

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, parsing, nsmutablearray

**The JSON source formatted with jsonviewer.stack.hu:**

[image: Json formatter]

**My Parse Method (simplified):**

```
- (void)parseMethod {

    // OTHER STUFF

    arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    

    NSURL *url2 = // THE URL SOURCE OF JSON OBJECT, ON A REMOTE SERVER

    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:5.0];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation2 = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request2
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request2, NSHTTPURLResponse *response2, id JSON)
                                         {
                                             arrayList = [JSON objectForKey:@"list"];

                                             // HERE I TRIED TO WRITE [arrayListPrev removeObjectAtIndex:0];

                                             NSMutableArray *arrayList1 = [arrayList valueForKey:@"list1"];
                                         }
                                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request2, NSHTTPURLResponse *response2, NSError *error2, id JSON2) { 
                                         }];
    [operation2 start];

}
```

**The problem:**
After the parsing I want to remove the FIRST OBJECT of array named "list", because I must populate the rows of a UITableView with all the values of list1 in the arrays EXCEPT the first ( list array->array number 0->list1 value of 0 ). I have tried the code:

```
[arrayList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

In several position but app crashes with error:**'-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'**... so what's the best way to REMOVE the FIRST object (array number 0) from that NSMutableArray *list AFTER the parsing, to ELIMINATE The list1 value of 0 object? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In spite of you write `arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Here, as i guess, you assign simple immutable array instance

`arrayList = [JSON objectForKey:@"list"];`

You can do this instead:

```
arrayList = [[JSON objectForKey:@"list"] mutableCopy];
[arrayList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thank you, Mikhail, the simplest solution! There is some problem to use the "mutableCopy" or also here it's autoreleasing? Im using ARC...

Comment: There are no problems - when you use arc you commonly don't think about retain and release in such situations

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are working with an `NSArray` and not an `NSMutableArray`. This is probably due to the fact your parser returns immutable objects. What you need to do is take that `NSArray`, create an `NSMutableArray` with it and then remove the first object

```
NSMutableArray *_arrayList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayList];
[_arrayList removeObjectAtIndex:0];
// dont forget to store your array wherever you need it
```

Comment: Thanks, Ismael! but sorry, if I have declared before the  arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; it was not ALREADY a NSMutableArray ?!

Comment: but after that you are doing `arrayList = [JSON objectForKey:@"list"];`. Anyway, the answer you accepted is the best way to go :) cheers

Answer (score 2):

The Error shows that your array is having value of immutable type.Use a mutable copy or initialize your arrayList with `-arrayWithArray:` method.Hope it fixes the problem.

Note: allocate `NSMutableArray` to initialize with `initWithCapacity` method

Answer (score 0):

As other's have suggested, you're working with an NSArray, which is not Mutable (Editable). I'm going to add my input though with a new function:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArrayList = [arrayList mutableCopy];
```

This creates a mutable copy of the array.